# Building my own on-off button for a PC

Tags: power-electronics, computers, atx, pc

I'm looking to build my own power button for my computer.

Most motherboards have a pair of `PWR_SW` pins that your case power button typically attaches to via two female pin connector wires (I don't know the correct term). This is the part I plan on replacing. Attached to some button like this for example: https://www.adafruit.com/product/558

I'm also aware you can short the two pins by touching them both at once with a screwdriver and most motherboards will just turn on– is this basically what a switch / button does? If I attach two wires to the button above and press the button– I'm guessing that essentially does what the screwdriver does and completes the circuit– turning the computer on?

Comment: `please bare with me` means `take off clothes`  .... the word you want is `bear`

Comment: a switch touches two wires together internally

Comment: your question appears to be about how a switch functions .... that makes all the references to the PC kind of irrelevant

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=knife+switch&ia=images&iax=images

Comment: There are some (leaked) motherboard schematics online. I recommend looking into those to seeing how a power button activates everything else in the circuit board (except for standby power of course)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a switch contains conductive parts that contact or separate according to how the switch is designed and operated.

The PC power switch creates a conductive metal path between the wires while while it is pressed.

If you can duplicate that sort of thing you can make a power switch for your PC.